# Making wordcloud from data frame

Tags: python, data-analysis, word-cloud

Suppose that in the right column we have the amount of times that each neighbourhood is appeared.
I want to create a wordcloud for the given data frame.
But when i tried to create it ,   neighbourhoods like **Neos Kosmos** or **Akadimia Platonos** get seperated as different words cause of the space character between the words that make up the name of the neighbourhood

This is the code that i've written

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000,height = 2000,background_color = 'white',stopwords = 
STOPWORDS).generate(str(df))
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 30),facecolor = 'k',edgecolor = 'k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

```
neighbourhood value
Plaka          1216
Neos Kosmos    952
Koukaki        883
Pangrati       683
Kolonaki       650  
Akadimia Platonos 555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` on your series, then use wordcloud's `generate_from_frequencies` to generate your cloud

```
my_list=['bat','cat','rat','gnat']

ser=pd.Series([' '.join([choice(my_list),choice(my_list)]) for i in range(100)])

ser.head()
0    bat cat
1    bat cat
2    rat rat
3    rat rat
4    rat rat

w=wordcloud.WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(ser.value_counts())

plt.imshow(w)
```

[image: WordCloud of Frequencies]

Comment: I tried it with **wordcloud.fitwords(df)** and it worked!!!!
Thank you anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark if my solution led you to your own, but if you found a solution that worked better/easier for you, it's also perfectly acceptable to write and accept your own answer. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with **wordcloud.fitwords(df)** and it worked!!!! Thank you anyway!